# Firebase Firestore error XMLHttpRequest is not defined developing google chrome extension MV3

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a google chrome extension with manifest version 3 using Firebase and Firestore for store user data.

When I try to write on the Firestore i'll get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`
[image]

My firebase-main.js looks like this:

```
import "/firebase-app.js";
import "/firebase-auth.js";
import "/firebase-firestore.js";
try {
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MYDATAHERE"
  authDomain: "MYDATAHERE",
  projectId: "MYDATAHERE",
  storageBucket: "MYDATAHERE",
  messagingSenderId: "MYDATAHERE",
  appId: "MYDATAHERE"
};

console.log("firebase main inizializing");
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(app);
const db = firebase.firestore();
console.log(db);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, resp) => {
  console.log("msg.command = " + msg.command);
  if(msg.command == "post"){
    console.log("msg = post");
    console.log("msg.data.extensionEmail is " + msg.data.extensionEmail);
    db.collection("users").doc(msg.data.extensionEmail).set({
        data: msg.data
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
  }
  sendResponse(true);
  return true;
})
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Inside my extension popup.js i'll send the message to firebase-main and the message is received but when it try to write on Firebase the error comes out.

I am using firebase-app,  firebase-firestore and firebase-auth 8.5 downloaded inside the main directory of the extension.

I read that XMLHttpRequest is no more supported with service worker in manifest version 3 but I can't find a way to write on the db.

Can anyone help me please?

I've already tryed to import xhr2 using the command `npm install xhr2` and import at the top of firebase-firestore.js without success.

I've tryed using newer/older versions of firebase-app,  firebase-firestore and firebase-auth.

Comment: What kind of script is firebase-firestore.js? Is that your service worker?

Comment: Okay, so I think I get it unfortunately. If you are trying to import scripts that rely on XMLHTTP requests and you are trying to run those out of your service worker, that won't work. You can only perform fetch requests in service workers.

Comment: Also, you would be exposing your API key in the extension files. I've tied in API's / DB's in my browser extension projects before and you need to do that separately. Create some endpoints you can hit and host the firebase code seperately.

Comment: Hi @JoeRidyard , thank you for your answer. firebase-main.js (you can see the code above) is the service worker. I've downloaded firebase-firestore.js from https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5/firebase-firestore.js because I had problems importing firebase files from web. Unfortunately I don't understand, how can I write/read the db?

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceWorkers in Chrome Extensions using Manifest V3 can no longer access XMLHTTPRequest and instead use fetch()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#workers). This means that you may have to find a polyfill for it, however, this does come with some inherint challenges once you do find a polyfill. One challenge is that XHR synchronous operations cannot be replicated in fetch completely since fetch is an asynchronous API by design. Additionally, you would need to place some trust in the authors of the polyfill that they are not doing anything nefarious with their polyfill library that you are using. If I was you, I would determine what functionality you are looking to use in Firestore and either call a cloud function from an HTTPS endpoint with the firebase functions you want or, if you are interested in querying firestore, utilizing the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) and the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make those commands.